# How to pass parameters in a cgi-perl on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, perl, cgi

I'm using Apache server on Fedora-20. I'm trying to run a perl-cgi program on my local server, but it's not working, I have attached my html and perl code.

html program:

```
<html>
<head><title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/fam.cgi" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This ran properly and outputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "hello world\n";
```

But when I pass a parameter, it doesn't work.

```
#!usr/bin/perl -wT 
use CGI;
my $username = param('username');
print header;
print start_html("Perl page");
print h2("hello $username");
print end_html;
```

I've already installed the cgi module. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add:

```
my $q = CGI->new();
my $username = $q->param('username');
...
```

So the whole should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new();
my $username = $q->param('username');

print $q->header();
print $q->start_html("Perl page");
print $q->h2("Hello, $username!\n");
print $q->end_html;
```

More info you can [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html).
Also in your file you are missing "/":

```
#!usr/bin/perl -wT
```

I think should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
```

Comment: Its also is not working... Internal server error. I already change mod by using this command `chmod 755 filename'

Comment: What is happening if run it from command line?

Comment: `Before failed complication aborted at line 6`

Comment: Anything else, syntax error or whatever?

Comment: there is no syntax error..

Comment: Answer is edited, check again.

Comment: now its not internal server error.. But param(username) is not dispalyed. Mean param is not passing.